# Parsing RSS news not working

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom, web-scraping

I would like to parse news titles and links from the following RSS page:

http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/CompanyNewsRSS.html?newsSource=RNS&companySymbol=LSE

I have tried using this code  (but it's not working):

```
<?php

$xml=("http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/CompanyNewsRSS.html?newsSource=RNS&companySymbol=LSE");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
  $title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo $title;
  echo $link;

}
?>
```

However the same code is working to get RSS titles and links from other RSS pages.. for example:

```
<?php

$xml=("https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=bcm.v&region=US&lang=en-US");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
  $title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo $title;
  echo $link;

}
?>
```

Do you have any idea on how to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you write the error you are getting so somebody can help you finding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Downloading Remote Documents

The problem is that you are trying to download remote document with `DOMDocument::load`. The method is capable of downloading remote files, but it doesn't set the `User-Agent` HTTP header, if it is not specified via [`user_agent`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent) INI setting. Some hosts are configured to reject HTTP requests, if the `User-Agent` header is absent. And the URL you pasted into the question returns `403 Forbidden`, if the header is missing.

So you should either set user agent via INI settings:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'MyCrawler/1.0');
$url = 'http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/CompanyNewsRSS.html?newsSource=RNS&companySymbol=LSE';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);
```

or download the document manually with `User-Agent` header set, e.g.:

```
$url = 'http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/CompanyNewsRSS.html?newsSource=RNS&companySymbol=LSE';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'MyCrawler/1.0');
$xml = curl_exec($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
```

## Traversing the DOM

The next problem with your code is that you are fully relying on specific DOM structure:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=5; $i++) {
  $title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
    ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

The are many possible cases where you code will not work as expected: less than 5 items, missing elements, empty document, etc. Besides, the code is not very readable. You should always check if the node exists before going deeper into its structure, e.g.:

```
$channels = $doc->getElementsByTagName('channel');
foreach ($channels as $channel) {
  // Print channel properties
  foreach ($channel->childNodes as $child) {
    if ($child->nodeType !== XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
      continue;
    }
    switch ($child->nodeName) {
      case 'title':
        echo "Title: ", $child->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
        break;
      case 'description':
        echo "Description: ", $child->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

You can parse the `item` elements in similar manner:

```
$items = $channel->getElementsByTagName('item');
foreach ($items as $item) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You can set a user agent in the libxml stream context, too. [libxml_set_streams_context()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php)

Comment: Thanks Ruslan!! Your answer was just perfect despite my not so clear question. Thanks allot!!!

Answer (score 1):

They have security in place when no user agent is set so you'll have to use curl and fake an user agent to get the xml content eg:

```
$url = "http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/CompanyNewsRSS.html?newsSource=RNS&companySymbol=LSE";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
```